# My Cypress tests fail in Jenkins but pass locally

Tags: jenkins, testing, cypress

I am trying to run my e2e tests in Jenkins. But, my Jenkins job fails with this error:

â”‚ Cypress:    4.0.1                                                                              â”‚
â”‚ Browser:    Electron 78 (headless)                                                             â”‚
â”‚ Specs:      1 found (examples\test.js)                                   â”‚

Running:  examples\test.js                                          (1 of 1)

Timed out waiting for the browser to connect. Retrying...

Timed out waiting for the browser to connect. Retrying again...

The browser never connected. Something is wrong. The tests cannot run. Aborting...

The tests pass locally.

Firstly, I had this problem with Cypress 3.8.2.

I tried with these solutions, founded on Internet:

- updating the version to 4.0.1
- removing baseUrl from cypress.json file
- following next steps: running Cypress, selecting "View App data" and deleting all files. Then, I closed Cypress and run it again to recreate the extensions
- changing the running command from npx cypress run to npx cypress open.

But, these solutions couldn't help me.

Does anybody have any idea how to resolve this problem?

Comment: Probably not really important, but what are these `â”`s? Do these characters really show up like that?

Comment: I don't know about this characters. But this error is very important for me to solve. This: 

Timed out waiting for the browser to connect. Retrying...

Timed out waiting for the browser to connect. Retrying again...

The browser never connected. Something is wrong. The tests cannot run. Aborting...

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am encountering the same issue.

Comment: is your Jenkins set up in a different server? or are you trying to execute Jenkins in your local?

Answer (score 1):

Try updating the Docker image from jenkins file if using.
It resolved mine.

for all cypress supported docker images here is git [link](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-docker-images/tree/master/browsers)